# Finding the datatype from the data

Tags: matlab

I have data in a matrix form, where each column represents a measurement.

Each column can either represent booleans, integers or continuous numbers.

- Booleans: `1` or `0`
- Integers:  `-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3`
- Continuous numbers `0.2, 5.0, 9.5, ...`

The matrix is large so **I would like an efficient way to do identify each column's type** automatically in Matlab.

---

Example Matrix:

```
1 0.2 3 . . .
0 4.5 2 . . .
1 6.0 1 . . .
1 7.0 2 . . .
0 9.5 3 . . .
0 8.0 2 . . .
```

- Column 1: switch 1/0
- Column 2: measured continuous value
- Column 3: number of something
- etc...

---

I would like to identify each type so that I can vary the values appropriately to understand the behaviour of the measured system. For instance:

```
if boolean
    value = ~value;      % Change switch/Boolean values to their opposite
end
if integer
    value = value + 1    % Increase integer values by 1
end
if continuous
    value = value + 0.1; % Increase continuous values by 0.1
end
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: @Wolfie thanks for your patience and willing to help. I updated the question. i hope its clear now. any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following method to define the type of a column:

```
isBool = all((data - ~(~(data))) == 0)
isInteger = all((data - round(data)) == 0) & ~isBool
isNumber = ~isBool & ~isInteger
```

This uses the following characteristics of each type

- Boolean: negating a boolean twice results in the same boolean
- Integer: rounding off an integer should result in the same integer (but skip the booleans)
- Floating point number: not a boolean nor an integer

**Future readers:** have a look at the comment of @Wolfie.

Comment: This is a good way of identifying these 3 different categories. **For future readers**, it's worth noting that this isn't *technically* type identification, since (for instance) an array intended as integers which is all ones would be identified as Boolean. For true type identification, **matrices must be of single type** and can be type-tested using the `is...` functions defined in the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data-type-identification.html). In this case, the entire matrix is likely stored as doubles.

Comment: @Wolfie Thanks wolfie you are correct, the matrix has been defined as double. I meant the elements of the matrix. Thanks for the insights of the problem. I really appreciate  your contributions to the community.